# Looking for a method to select non adjacent parts of text in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selection

Certain apps let the user select non-adjacent text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + selection, unfortunately, Google Chrome isn't one of them. Is there some workaround that makes it possible to select multiple non-contiguous parts of text in chrome?

Answer (score -1):

I use the merge feature in Alfred App as a workaround. It lets use copy multiple things then paste them in a list.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.